# Given grammar ambiguous or not?

Tags: programming-languages, grammar, context-free-grammar, language-theory

Consider the grammar below...

```
bexp -> bterm | bterm ‘||’ bexp
bterm -> bfact | bfact ‘&&’ bterm
bfact -> true | false | id | ‘(‘ bexp ‘)’
```

Suppose we extend BEXP with the '!' operator for negation by changing the bfact rule as follows:-

```
bfact -> true | false | id | '(' bexp ')' | '!' bexp
```

Lets call this extended grammar BEXP2. How can I prove that it is ambiguous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove that it is ambiguous by finding a string with two parses :)

In this case, try `!id&&id`. Is that `(!id)&&id` or `!(id&&id)`

Comment: I'm still not sure how I can get 2 parses out of !id&&id.

Comment: @sparta93: Just do the rightmost derivations. (Or leftmost, if you prefer.) Remember that in a rightmost derivation, you always derive the rightmost non-terminal at every step. If this is homework (or even if not), you will learn better by doing it. But anyway: `bexp->bterm->bfact&&bterm->bfact&&bfact->bfact&&id->!bexp&&id->!bterm&&i->!bfact&&id->!id&&id`. `bexp->bterm->bfact->!bexp->!bterm->!bfact->!bfact&&bterm->!bfact&&bfact->!bfact&&id->!id&&id`. Now you should draw the corresponding parse trees.